# atexit(3) in Perl: `END {}` or `$SIG{__DIE__}`?

Tags: perl, signals, die, atexit

I'm wondering: When you detect you need to clean up at the end of the program (excluding "end of block"), you want to "queue an exit handler" that does the cleanup at some later time.
In most cases you want the cleanup to happen even if the user presses ^C (SIGINT), so I wonder:

When installing possibly multiple exit handlers, should it be done with `END` blocks, or should it be done using `$SIG{__DIE__}` handlers (if so, how to "queue" them?)?

The manual says processes terminated by signals would skip the `END` blocks, to is that a no-go for them?
Likewise, when a process is terminated by a signal, is the `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler called at all ("man perlvar" is silent on that), or do I have to install a handler for each possible signal, too?

Answer (score 3):

> The manual says processes terminated by signals would skip the END block ...

This is because unless the application itself installs a signal handler, the default action for most signals is to forcibly kill the process. This means there is no way for the application to run their own cleanups in this case. The process cleanup of the OS (closing files, sockets, ...) is still done though.

If you want to have your own cleanup you need to catch the signal using `%SIG`. If you then call `exit` from inside the signal handler it will also run `END` functions in your program. Note that not all signals can be catched.

> ... when a process is terminated by a signal, is the `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler called at all

`$SIG{__DIE__}` is not relevant here. It will not be called on signals, but if the program throws a fatal exception (i.e. `die`).

Answer (score 2):

To "*queue an exit handler*", ala `atexit(3)`, in Perl use [END blocks](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END); that's precisely what they are for.   There may be multiple ones, executed in order reverse of how they come in code (they run from the back one by one).  Forks inherit parent's `END` blocks so they'll run on child's exit.  If that is not desired one way out is to exit a child process using [POSIX::_exit](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX#_exit), which bypasses `END` blocks.<sup>†</sup>  Please see docs to accustom yourself with the library.

The `END` blocks run on `exit` and `die`, but not on termination from signals (that terminate the program -- not all do), as you noticed, so also install signal handlers.  Set up a suitable one for each signal.  To have handlers run `END` blocks as well use `exit` in them.

The `$SIG{__DIE__}` is called when an exception (`die`) is thrown, and while that can be triggered by a variety of situations this is not a catch-all.  It's not really a signal handler at all either, since `die` isn't a signal, but is rather a hook into it.  Signals that terminate the program do not use `die` so this hook won't run.

Handlers can be chain-assigned if there is no reason to distinguish their behavior:

```
$SIG{INT} = $SIG{TERM} = ... = sub { say "Caught $_[0]"; .... };
```

Note also the core [sigtrap](https://perldoc.perl.org/sigtrap) for signal handling.  Apart from other functionality the above is

```
use sigtrap 'handler' => \&sig_handler, qw(INT TERM);
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  Along with much else, as it closes the process "*immediately*."  It's a bit radical measure. See man pages for C's `_exit`, what this is "*identical to*," both in sections 2 (Linux) and 3 (POSIX).

Comment: Re "*`$SIG{__DIE__}` indeed covers a variety of situations*", It's called when an exception thrown (whether it will be caught or not), and it's only called in that one situation.

Comment: Re "*`POSIX::_exit`, which bypasses `END` blocks*", and a whole lot more. Nothing gets destroyed. Which means that file buffers don't get flushed.

Comment: What I'm a bit worried about `END` is this: If (e.g. at the end of a block) you did the cleanup explicitly, the cleanup handler should be either deactivated or has to be idempotent. And it seems it's easier with `$SIG` than using `END` blocks. I mean: Can you deactivate an `END` block?

Comment: @U.Windl  "_If (...) you did the cleanup explicitly, the cleanup handler should be either deactivated or has to be idempotent._" --  That'd be a concern for any cleanup.  For one, we generally write code to release resources _if they're held/open_, not unconditionally.  Also, how would any one `END` block run again? It runs _after_ the `RUN` phase finished.  One exception I can think of is in child processes, which is why I mention it.

Comment: @U.Windl  As for `END` blocks vs signal handlers -- yhey are a bit orthogonal (almost) and it's not one-or-the-other:  Can't use signal handlers for normal program termination or `exit`; and vice-versa, a signal can't be handled by an `END` block (while you can trigger it out of a handler).  If you want to ensure custom cleanup you do need both.   But to compare, if anything `END` blocks far more versatile, so to say.

Comment: @ikegami (1) "_it's only called in that one situation_"  -- sure, but that can arise out of _many_ situations.  From dividing by zero to messing up I/O to misusing any old library which croaks. While a signal is a signal.  That's what I mean.  But I see what you are saying and I rephrased it.  (2)  As for `POSIX::_exit` -- didn't want to spread out, that itself was a side comment already.  But you are right, it's asking for a comment.  Added a footnote.  All this is tricky to address in a contained manner.  Thank you for comments.

Comment: Re "*sure, but that can arise out of many situations. While a signal is a signal*", By that logic, a signal arises from a lot of different situations. User initiated. Writing to a closed pipe. Using too many resources. etc

Answer (score 1):

After having read https://stackoverflow.com/a/77302322/6607497 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/77303688/6607497, and after some extra thinking, I decided to write my own mechanism, ignoring `END` blocks:

I'll handle an array of closures and a `cleanup` routine that will call the queue of closures, then flush it:

```perl
my @cleanup_queue;                      # cleanup queue

# process the cleanup queue, then clear the queue
sub cleanup()
{
    foreach (@cleanup_queue) {
        $_->();
    }
}
```

Then I use `cleanup` in three places:

1. Signal handler(s)
2. Die handler
3. Normal exit

The handlers I needed thus were:

```perl
$SIG{'__DIE__'} = sub {
    my $msg = $_[0];

    cleanup();
    die $msg;                           # actually die
};

$SIG{'INT'} = $SIG{'TERM'} = sub {
    cleanup();
    $SIG{$_[0]} = 'DEFAULT';
    kill($_[0], $$);                    # execute default action
};
```

The cleanup closures are added in reverse order, like this:

```perl
{
#...
    unshift(
        @cleanup_queue,
        sub () {
            while (my ($pid, $peername) = each %connections) {
                child_delete($pid);
            }
        });
#...
    cleanup();
}
```

Tested with clean exits, signals and forced `die`.

Maybe I duplicated some of the Perl internals, but now I have (almost) full control of the code being involved.